# Clickhouse - How often clickhouse triggers a merge operation and how to control it?

Tags: olap, clickhouse

I read that 10-15 mins after insert into a merge-tree table,  Clickhouse triggers a merge-operations.
Is there a way to tell it to reduce that interval, to make it merge a bit more often?

also, I noticed that even in old partitions, there are several parts and not only one, how come?

Answer (score 1):

No control. No interval.

You should not rely on a merge process. It has own complicated algorithm to balance number of parts. Merge has no goal to do final merge -- to make 1 part because it's not efficient and wasting of disk I/O and CPU.

You can call unscheduled forced merge using 'optimize table' command.